# ASP.NET MVC - What does the *Context pattern symbolize?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So in ASP.NET MVC you very often see the pattern that you have objects with a related *Context object, like Request/RequestContext View/ViewContext and Controller/ControllerContext.

I do know how to work within the ASP.NET MVC pipeline, but I never *really* understood the overarching pattern with these Context classes. What does a *Context class symbolize? Can someone shed a bit more light on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**Context** classes such `ViewContext` and `ControllerContext` maintain the state of this single modules during the request life cycle. This context objects were implemented based on `State Pattern`, defined as:

> "Allow an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class."

Answer (score 0):

controllers in the MVC pattern are concerned with the flow of the application.

Controller class inherits `ControllerBase` class, which in turn implements the methods of `IController` interface.

**IController interface:**

The `IController` interface exposes `Execute()` method, that gets executed when a request is made for the controller. It accepts an object of `RequestContext` class, which encapsulates information about an `HTTP request` that matches a defined route, using the HttpContext and RouteData properties

**ControllerBase class:**

The abstract ControllerBase class represents the base class for all MVC controllers.

The ControllerBase class acts as a `wrapper on top of the IController interface`. The Execute() method of ControllerBase class is responsible for creating the **ControllerContext**, which provides the MVC specific context for the current request much in the same way that an `instance of HttpContext` provides the context for ASP.NET, providing request and response, URL and server information, among other elements.